# selfMask() in GEE masking negative values as well?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am currently trying to use `.selfMask()` on a raster image in GEE. The definition of the selfMask function is:

> Updates an image's mask at all positions where the existing mask is not zero

However, this is not true. It masks values that are negative as well; when running the following piece of code you'll notice all areas featuring negative temperatures are being masked, despite these being non-null areas. Has anyone encountered this issue before? Is this normal?

```
var data = ee
  .Image('WORLDCLIM/V1/BIO')
  .select('bio06')
  .selfMask()
Map.addLayer(data,{},'Data')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal (if a little surprising).

> Updates an image's mask at all positions where the existing mask is not zero...

This means that the mask is only updated in previously unmasked areas. In other words, you can't change an existing masked pixel with `updateMask`. The rest of the description explains what values are set in the image mask:

> ...using the value of the image as the new mask value.

Masks in Earth Engine are clamped 0-1, so negative values in your image were clamped to zero (fully masked) and large values were clamped to 1 (fully unmasked). Any values between 0-1 would be partially masked.

To demonstrate, you can mask directly with a negative value and the resulting image will be fully masked:

```js
var data = ee
  .Image('WORLDCLIM/V1/BIO')
  .select('bio06')
  .mask(-1);

Map.addLayer(data, {} ,'Data')
```